# Como usar loop no shell usando o lowriter

Tags: linux, loop, script, shell, sh

Eu estou tentando executar o lowriter(gerar PDF) em loop, dessa maneira:

```
#!/bin/sh

ROOT_DIRECTORY="docs"

function count_files()
{
    ls -lR $ROOT_DIRECTORY/*.doc | wc -l
}

function get_number_folders()
{
    expr $(count_files) / 100 + 1
}

function create_folders_and_fill_with_files()
{
    for num in $(seq 1 $(get_number_folders))
    do
        #mkdir $ROOT_DIRECTORY/$num
        mv `ls $ROOT_DIRECTORY/*.doc | head -100` $ROOT_DIRECTORY/$num/
        convert_to_pdf $ROOT_DIRECTORY $num
    done
}

function convert_to_pdf()
{
    lowriter -convert-to pdf --outdir ./docs/ $1/$2/*.doc --headless
    set -x
}

create_folders_and_fill_with_files
```

Aparentemente o comando está certo, o único problema é que ele roda 1 única vez e para, não executa novamente, como eu consigo executar o lowriter várias vezes?

Grato

Answer (score 0):

Talvez esteja estourando no lowriter? Tente redirecionar o `stderr` para o `stdout` para ver o que pode estar ocorrendo:

```bsh
lowriter -convert-to pdf --outdir ./docs/ $1/$2/*.doc --headless 2>&1
```